# Computing a 512 bit hash

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hash

Ethers.js has this 512 bit hash function `ethers.utils.sha512`, but as far as I can tell there is no OPCODE or precompiled contract for doing this. There seems to be some implementations in solidity itself but those don't seem safe or gas efficient.

So why does Ethers.js have this function? Am I wrong? Is there a reasonable way to compute a 512 bit hash in Ethereum?